# How do I split my list into columns

Tags: php, html-lists, multiple-columns

Here is my code used for my footer nav, how do I split my list into columns with 5 titles in each column:

```
<ul class="footerNav footnav1">
     <?php $parents = table_fetch_rows('page', 'status = 1 AND footer_nav = 1 AND parent_id < 0', 'position ASC'); ?>
     <?php if(count($parents) > 0): ?>
         <?php foreach($parents as $key => $parent): ?>
             <li><a href="<?php echo getRewriteUrl('page', $parent['id']); ?>"><?php echo $parent['menu_title']; ?></a></li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
</ul><!-- footerNav -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$parents = table_fetch_rows('page', 'status = 1 AND footer_nav = 1 AND parent_id < 0', 'position ASC');
if(count($parents) > 0) {
    echo '<ul class="footerNav footnav1">';
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($parents as $key => $parent){
         ?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo getRewriteUrl('page', $parent['id']); ?>"><?php echo $parent['menu_title']; ?></a></li>
         <?php
         if($counter %5 ==0){ 
             echo '</ul><ul class="footerNav footnav1">';
         }
         $counter++;
    }
    echo '</ul><!-- footerNav -->';
}?>
```